# Reading an Excel file into a DataTable includes system-defined columns

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing a program to read excel using c# and store in a `DataTable`. When I check the columns in my `DataTable` while debugging, I see system columns like `Table_Schema`, `Table_Catalog`, `Table_Name`, `Table_Type` etc. How do I exclude these unwanted columns?

My code:

```
string sSheetName = null;
            string sConnection = null;
            int nOutputRow = 0;
            DataTable dtTablesList = default(DataTable);
            OleDbCommand oleExcelCommand = default(OleDbCommand);
            OleDbConnection oleExcelConnection = default(OleDbConnection);

            sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + txtFileName.Text + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            oleExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
            oleExcelConnection.Open();

            dtTablesList = oleExcelConnection.GetSchema("Tables");

            if (dtTablesList.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                sSheetName = dtTablesList.Rows[0].Field<string>("TABLE_NAME");
            }

            dtTablesList.Clear();
            dtTablesList.Dispose();


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sSheetName))
            {
                oleExcelCommand = oleExcelConnection.CreateCommand();
                string commandText = "Select * From [" + sSheetName + "]";

                oleExcelCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OleDbDataAdapter daexcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(commandText, oleExcelConnection);
                dtTablesList.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                daexcel.Fill(dtTablesList);
            }
            oleExcelConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Are you reading XLS or XLSX?

Comment: I am reading xlsx.

Comment: Then try using this connection string: `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtFileName.Text + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';`

Comment: I get error The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. I still dont think it is the provider issue. Is there someway we can specify restrictions to system columns

Comment: See this link for how to install the missing driver: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb

Comment: Though the Ace provider issue resolved , the issue with system column names didnt. As I said earlier, I dont think it was to do with the provider